# Proof question on maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: self-study, estimation

Let $Y$ be independent and identically distributed normal with mean $2\mu$ and variance $16$.

Show that $\frac{\bar y}{2}$ is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\mu$.

Comment: As a routine textbook type question, this counts as `self-study`. Please add the `self-study` tag and review its [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). With that in mind, what have you tried, and where does your difficulty lie?

Answer (score 1):

You can use invariance property of Maximum Likelihood estimator:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood

If alpha_hat=g(theta_hat) then theta_hat is MLE for alpha_hat.

And notice that 1/2 is jacobian for transformation of alpha=2*theta and average of y is MLE for myy.

Comment: Why does anyone need to consider the Jacobian?  There is no integration over the parameters.